# Laravel 5.2 Using Associate to Update a BelongsTo Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Route Model Binding to get a User instance then update it if validation passes, and then update the associated belongs to relationship between User and Profile, but I keep getting an error.  The update occurs on the User, but fails on updating the Profile.  From what I've understood from the docs this appears to be correct.  I can access Profile data using `$user->profile` so the relationship appears to be okay in the User and UserProfile models.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this controller action:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username'     => 'required|max:32|unique:users',
        'email'        => 'required|email|max:128|unique:users',
        'first_name'   => 'required',
        'last_name'    => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)\.]*)$/',
    ]);

    $user->update($request->all());

    $profile = new UserProfile($request->all());
    // Also tried:
    //$profile = UserProfile::where(['user_id' => $user->id])->first();

    $user->profile()->associate($profile);
    $user->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => trans('user.updated'),
    ]);
}
```

**Error**

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()
```

**User Model Relationships**

```
/**
 * A user has-one profile.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
}
```

**UserProfile Model Relationship**

```
/**
 * A user profile belongs to a user.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Solution**

```
$user->fill($request->all())->save();

$profile = UserProfile::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
$profile->fill($request->all());
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Comment: You should associate a model instance of profile.

Comment: Could you show the profile() function, just in case...

Comment: Hi @sniels, I just updated the question with the model relationships.

Comment: @mtpultz in the documentation, I read that you use the 'associate'-method for 'belongsTo' relations. So I think you might have to swap `$this->hasOne` and `$this->belongsTo`. Or associate via profile: `$profile->user()->associate($user);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must retrieve or create new `profile` entity first and put it in `$profile`. Also, you have One-to-one relation here, so you should save your user's profile like this:

```php
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with the addition of `new UserProfile($request->all());`, but I still seem to be getting the same error.

Comment: Here, your profile and user should have an ID. Try to retrieve existing profile first: `$profile = Profile::where('user_id', $user->id)->first()`

Comment: You've updated the code and it seems you have On-to-one relation, so you should save it with: `$user->profile()->save($profile);`

Comment: Wasn't there a `fill()` for models at some point so I could go `$profile = Profile::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();` then `$profile->fill($request->all());` and then `$user->profile()->save($profile)'`, but instead it seems you have to `$profile->first_name = 'test'` etc then save.

Comment: Yes, you can use mass assigment. You should fill the $fillable array first: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with the solution you've indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username'     => 'required|max:32|unique:users',
        'email'        => 'required|email|max:128|unique:users',
        'first_name'   => 'required',
        'last_name'    => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)\.]*)$/',
    ]);

    $profile = UserProfile::create($request->all());

    $user->profile()->associate($profile);

    $user->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => trans('user.updated'),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this appears to create a new record in Profile when one already exists.